# MySQL Query - Getting unique pairs with the max variable

Tags: mysql, sql

Edit: I realize that I did not do a good job of providing the background. So, changes will be made to the entire initial question.

I am currently working with three tables as shown below.

```
create table Movie(mID integer, title varchar(100), year integer, director varchar(100));
create table Reviewer(rID integer, name varchar(100));
create table Rating(rID integer, mID integer, stars integer, ratingDate date);

insert into Movie values(101, 'Gone with the Wind', 1939, 'Victor Fleming');
insert into Movie values(102, 'Star Wars', 1977, 'George Lucas');
insert into Movie values(103, 'The Sound of Music', 1965, 'Robert Wise');
insert into Movie values(104, 'E.T.', 1982, 'Steven Spielberg');
insert into Movie values(105, 'Titanic', 1997, 'James Cameron');
insert into Movie values(106, 'Snow White', 1937, null);
insert into Movie values(107, 'Avatar', 2009, 'James Cameron');
insert into Movie values(108, 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', 1981, 'Steven Spielberg');

insert into Reviewer values(201, 'Sarah Martinez');
insert into Reviewer values(202, 'Daniel Lewis');
insert into Reviewer values(203, 'Brittany Harris');
insert into Reviewer values(204, 'Mike Anderson');
insert into Reviewer values(205, 'Chris Jackson');
insert into Reviewer values(206, 'Elizabeth Thomas');
insert into Reviewer values(207, 'James Cameron');
insert into Reviewer values(208, 'Ashley White');

insert into Rating values(201, 101, 2, date_format('2012-01-22','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(201, 101, 4, date_format('2013-01-27','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(202, 106, 4, null);
insert into Rating values(203, 103, 2, date_format('2008-01-20','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(203, 108, 4, date_format('2002-01-12','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(203, 108, 2, date_format('2009-01-30','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(204, 101, 3, date_format('2010-01-09','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(205, 103, 3, date_format('2010-01-27','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(205, 104, 2, date_format('2010-01-22','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(205, 108, 4, null);
insert into Rating values(206, 107, 3, date_format('2013-01-15','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(206, 106, 5, date_format('2014-01-19','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(207, 107, 5, date_format('2000-01-20','%Y-%m-%d'));
insert into Rating values(208, 104, 3, date_format('1999-01-02','%Y-%m-%d'));
```

How should I get each movie that has at least one rating, find the movie title and the total number of stars, the highest star, and the reviewer who gave the highest star?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: In your example mId 108 has two names with the same rating of 4. What should happen then?

Answer (score 0):

Use window function:

```
with rw as (
select Movie.mID, max(rating.stars) as rating, name
from movie left join rating on movie.mID=rating.mID
    left join Reviewer on rating.rID=Reviewer.rID
group by Movie.mID, name
),

rated as (
select mID, rating, name,
rank() over (partition by mID order by rating desc) as rnk
from rw
)

select mID, rating, name from rated outr 
where rnk=
    (select min(rnk) from rated innr where innr.mID=outr.mID)
```

Comment: Presumably this should be a picture

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?

Comment: Hi @Vad1m, I updated the question. Perhaps this is more informative to construct the answer. I apologize that it was too vague in the beginning. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @HSChan I've just edited answer. We have three problems with this script: 1. There are movies without rating. This answer provides rows with NULL values in this case. 2. Several reviewers provided more than one rating. Script returns the maximal value for each rewiever. 3. The movie №108 has two ratings with the same values. Query returns both ratings and their rewievers. Please check whether this answer is what you want

Comment: @Vad1m Thank you so much! I appreciate your help! It works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySQL MAX() function with WHERE clause to specify conditions ex largest payment in a specific year ie to return the largest value, this can be implemented to achieve your goals check the below example

```
 SELECT 
    MAX(amount) largest_payment_2004
FROM
    payments
WHERE
    YEAR(paymentDate) = 2004;
```